# spring rest Pageable send only content

Tags: java, spring, rest

Hello I have rest api with make  pageable

```
 @GetMapping("/all")
    public Page<Chbyphone_current> getAllUsers(
            @RequestParam Optional<String> active_from,
            @RequestParam Optional<Integer> page,
            @RequestParam Optional<String> sortBy) {

    return cbpc.findByDate(active_from.orElse("_"),
             PageRequest.of(
                    page.orElse(0), 1000,
                    Sort.Direction.ASC, sortBy.orElse("id")));
}
```

and it give me content ,pageable,sort ,and this is my question how can i force to send only content without ,pageable and sort

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public List<Chbyphone_current> getAllUsers(
            @RequestParam Optional<String> active_from,
            @RequestParam Optional<Integer> page,
            @RequestParam Optional<String> sortBy) {

    return cbpc.findByDate(active_from.orElse("_"),
             PageRequest.of(
                    page.orElse(0), 1000,
                    Sort.Direction.ASC, sortBy.orElse("id")))
             .getContent();
}
```